# Where do i begin diagnosing PostgreSQL performance problems?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-performance, postgresql-9.6, sqlperformance

I have a table called `modifications` with 42 columns and 84M rows. Total size is 64GB.

I am running Postgres 9.6.11 on Amazon RDS with 16GB of RAM on a db.m4.xlarge instance.

When i run a simple `SELECT count(*) FROM modifications;` it takes 380 seconds to finish executing.

When i run `SELECT * FROM modifications WHERE post_date = '2016-05-03';` to limit to a single date, it takes 156 seconds to return the 4.6M rows in the result.

When i limit the result set even further to about 1M rows, the query still takes over 100 seconds to complete.

I know these are large result sets, but i'm fairly novice about database query performance testing, so i'd like some pointers about what to try.

I've run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on these queries, but i'm not sure exactly what to do. Many of these queries are very simple and don't have clear ways to restructure them to improve performance.

I've also tried adding more indexes…i have indexes on each of the most commonly queried columns.

I am using the default settings for AWS RDS PostgreSQL configuration and have tried tweaking the `work_mem` settings using `SET LOCAL work_mem = 'XXXMB'`. That has not made a difference. Other default settings for things like `shared_buffers` (0.5GB) and `effective_cache_size` (0.5GB) are reasonably set.

Any advice or strategies on how to approach troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know in comments if i should include more information.

EDIT: Here's the execution plan for the last `SELECT` query

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on modifications  (cost=479407.01..1692971.07 rows=460492 width=279)
  Recheck Cond: ((post_date = '2016-05-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (change_type = 'residence_address_line_1'::text))
  ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=479407.01..479407.01 rows=460492 width=0)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on modifications_post_date_idx  (cost=0.00..130733.87 rows=4478040 width=0)
              Index Cond: (post_date = '2016-05-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on modifications_change_type_idx  (cost=0.00..348442.64 rows=8677610 width=0)
              Index Cond: (change_type = 'residence_address_line_1'::text)
```

Comment: You should use skinny tables for most queries. Good indexing should make it fast as well. Where do I begin? Include the execution plan for each query in the question. Normally you should start by finding the source of the problem using `explain select ...`. Post the results in this question. Throwing more hardware or resources at it rarely helps.

Comment: @the-impaler Added an execution plan to the post. 84M rows is a lot, but i feel like there are plenty of other people who have tables even larger than this who don't have basic performance problems like this.

Comment: @NicholasTulach Are you sure that's the plan for the query? The plan includes two predicates... one that reads `change_type = 'residence_address_line_1'::text` that I don't see in your query. And 84 millios rows should not be a problem if you are processing 1k, 10k, or 100k at a time.

Comment: It is the plan for the `When i limit the result set even further to about 1M rows` one i mention after.

Comment: "db.m4.xlarge instance" With RDS, you get to pick your storage type and size independently of instance size.    What is your IO type and size?

Comment: "i have indexes on each of the most commonly queried columns" - Do you mean one index per column? This seldom helps. Usually you want an index on all the columns used in the `WHERE` clause, e.g. `create index idx on modifications (post_date, change_type)`. And the order matters, too. If `change_type` is more restrictive than `post_date`, then you may want `create index idx on modifications (change_type, post_date)` instead. Sometimes I provide multiple indexes and then use `EXPLAIN` to see which are actually used by my queries and I drop the others.

Answer (score 1):

You should turn track_io_timing on, then you should do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` to look at the query's performance.

For the query whose plan you showed, it would probably be optimal to have a multi-column index on `(change_type, post_date)`.  But it isn't feasible to have hundreds of multi-column indexes to support hundreds of different queries.  So you should look at the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for that query both with the multicolumn index, and with the two single column indexes.

You have listed 3 dramatically different queries.  Which one is like the ones you care about most?  You generally need to optimize the query which gives you the results you need, you can't pick among very different queries based on how easy they are to optimize.

Comment: The queries i listed were just examples of very slow, basic queries against a large table. I understand that i need to optimize specific queries. I'm trying to learn strategies that i can apply to evaluating query performance. Can you explain is more detail how i use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` or provide a link to an explanation of how this differs from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`?

Comment: The output of EXPLAIN is supposed to be self-describing (although it isn't always successful at that), so it only very tersely described at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html .